# I need to increase php timelimit in free hosting account of 000webhost.com?

Tags: php

I tried adding the following in *.htaccess file*

```
php_value max_execution_time 0
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just put it below < ?php before any output

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Inside the php file you're executing

Comment: Already tried it but my free hosting doesn't seem to allow it. Anyways Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ini_set, or set_time_limit() to set this value:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600) // set execution time to 600 seconds
set_time_limit(600)
```

Note:
- You can not change this value if PHP is running under [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)
- The time will be started after this setting. Meaning after the setting is set, the time is start from 0.